# ASP.NET MVC Authentication by redirection to the login page and then back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC web site.
I have many actions which require authentication to be performed. So, I need the user to get redirected to the login page, and after login (if successful) to be redirected back.
So what I want to do now is to build a new class, smth. kind of seen below:

```
class AuthChecker
 {
    public AuthChecker(string authActionName, string authControllerName)
    {
      //...
    }

    public ActionResult InvokeIfAuthenticated(Func<ActionResult> body, string errorNoAuth, string returnUrl)
    {
         if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
         {
           return body();
         }
         else
         {
           //set returnUrl and return RedirectToAction(authAction);
         }
    }
 }
```

So is that okay, or there is some out-of-box solution to manage this situation?
Or maybe there is some better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `Authorize` attribute.

For example [from the link below]:

```
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult AuthenticatedUsers()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
 public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [Authorize(Users = "Betty, Johnny")]
 public ActionResult SpecificUserOnly()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

[Restrict Access to an Action Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381413.aspx)

Comment: Will it let the user be redirected to same action after login?